# Обратный отсчёт до даты e-timer

Tags: php, javascript, время, таймер, timestamp

Использую на сайте e-timer. нужно сделать обратный отсчёт каждый день до 20-00 если данное время пришло то делать отсчёт до следушего дня 20-00. Надо это все дело привязать к московскому времени. Чтоб на сайте для всех таймер работал по московскому времени не привязываясь к локальному времени. Как я понял нужно привезать счётчик к серверному времени а не к локальному времени пользователя.

Вот в таком формате счетчик принемает дату до которой будет считать
 etDate: "07.09.2018.0.0"

Я сделал на php маленький скрип (конечно он кривой).

```
    $hour = date('H');

    if ($hour >= 19 && $hour <= 24  ) {
        $date = new DateTime('+1 days');
    } else {
        $date = new DateTime('+0 days');
    }
```

Он собственно и передает данные в счётчик

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".eTimer").eTimer({
        etType: 0,
        etDate: "<?php echo $date->format('d.m.Y');?>.19.00",
    });
});
```

Это все работает... Но привязано к локальному времени пользвоателя. Повторюсь надо чтоб таймер считал только по московскому времеени для всех.   Еще надо использовать только данный таймер.

ссылка на таймер https://e-timer.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Передаем на клиент локальное время сервера и уже на клиенте считаем разницу между временем клиента и сервер. Потом эту разницу добавляем к времени в таймере.
Определяем целевую дату:

```
$hour = date('H');
if ($hour >= 19 && $hour <= 24  ) {
    $date = new DateTime('tomorrow 19:00');
} else {
    $date = new DateTime('today 19:00');
}
```

Код для старницы:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var serverTime = new Date(<?=(new DateTime())->getTimestamp()?>*1000);
    var localTime = new Date();
    var diff = serverTime - localTime;
    var targetTime = new Date(<?=$date->getTimestamp()?>*1000));
    targetTime.setTime(targetTime.getTime() + diff);

    jQuery(".eTimer").eTimer({
        etType: 0,
        etDate: targetTime.getDate() + '.' + (targetTime.getMonth() + 1) + '.'+  targetTime.getFullYear() + '.' +  targetTime.getHours()+ '.' + targetTime.getMinutes() ,
    });
});
```

Comment: А подскажите как работать только с МСк временем.  Код счетчика в открытом доступе..

Comment: Передавать пользователю время с учетом разницы между его временем и МСК

Answer (score 0):

Этот вариант привязан к смещению `+3`, то есть не переходит на летнее время и зимнее сам. Хороший вариант привязывать дату к часовому поясу через формат `Europe/Moscow` для этого можно воспользоваться [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```js
// в примере используется текущая дата + 24 часа
// дату можно указывать просто '2018-10-20 20:00'
const end = Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 
const endDate = calcTime(new Date(end))

setInterval(() => {
  const result = getTimeRemaining(endDate)
  let formated = ''
  
  for (let part in result)
    formated += `${part}: ${result[part]} | `
  // const formated = Object.values(result).join(':')

  display.innerHTML = formated.slice(0, -2)
}, 500)

function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  const t = endtime - calcTime()
  let obj = {
    days: t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) | 0,
    hours: t / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24 | 0,
    minutes: t / 1000 / 60 % 60 | 0,
    seconds: t / 1000 % 60 | 0
  }

  for (let key in obj)
    obj[key] = ('0' + obj[key]).slice(-2)
  
  return obj
}

// дата с нужным смещением
function calcTime(d = new Date(), offset = 3) {
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)

    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset))

    return nd
}
```

```html
<span id="display"></span>
```