# Таймер обратного отсчета привязаный к московскому времени

Tags: php, javascript, таймер

в этой теме [обратноый отсчёт до даты e-timer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878038/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-e-timer/878319#878319)
обяснили что e-timer не может считать по московскому времени а берет время с пк пользователя.

Подскажите таймер который будет работать только с московским временем не зависимо от времени на пк пользователя.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью библиотеки  [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) можно  вывести [текущее время с учетом часового пояса](https://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```js
moment.locale('ru');
moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/Moscow");
alert(moment().format("LTS"))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Время можно передать с хоста во время генерации страницы. Или асинхронно передавать уже на открытую страницу (ajax, ws). Само время можно получить на одном из сервисов которые на этом зарабатывают. Например, [Time Zone Database](https://timezonedb.com/references/get-time-zone). Другие легко гугляться по "api точное время".